# How the sequence ${1, 4, 9, ..., n^2}$ can be written as sum of few arithmetic sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How a the sequence ${1, 4, 9, ..., n^2}$ can be written as sum of few arithmetic sequences? Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for $n^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n 2i-1$?

Comment: It's equal to this sequence: $1,1+3,1+3+5,1+3+5+7,\dots$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @columbus8myhw actually I'm trying to prove that $1 + 4 + 16 + n^2 = \frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}$ so i thought it might be good idea to write it as few athematic sequence then with them I can prove

Comment: Try to prove by induction.

Comment: Sum of arithmetic sequences is an arithmetic progressions, so you can't express 1,4,9 or any extension of it like that.

Comment: 1) Let $S(n)=1+2+\dotsb+n^2$. What is $S(n)-S(n-1)$? 2) Now, assume $S(n)=an^3+bn^2+cn+d$—that is, assume $S(n)$ is a cubic polynomial. Can you solve for $a,b,c,$ and $d$?